# Мне кажется, что запятая не нужна. А вы что думаете?

Tags: запятые

Мне кажется, что запятая не нужна. А вы что думаете?

> Моё предназначение среди остальных котов, к нашей команде, «Филолокэты», принадлежащим, — это, являясь котом(,) полным фантазии и воображения, придумывать объяснения того, почему существуют те или иные орфононимы и как же всё-таки по-лëгкому и по-эффективному запомнить, какие составляющие каждого орфононима пишутся именно так-таки, а не эдаки.

Comment: Мм... Лео, а разве есть такое слово — "орфононим"? Если это ваш неологизм, то, пожалуйста, объясните — чего же ж это такое?

Comment: Скоро, Римм, скоро.

Comment: А я думаю, что надоели бредовые вопросы, за которыми других тем уже не видно. Форум СПАМА, где ничего от форума уже не осталось. А ведь об этом было сказано еще очень давно, а я эти вопросы защищала. И еще словечко было тогда сказано, тоже верное. Из пяти букв, на М начинается. Догадайтесь, какое. И это при всем том, что сам Лео мне нравится. Он способный, талантливый, можно сказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А *мы* думаем, что запятая нужна.

> **1.** Обособляются (отделяются запятой, а в середине предложения выделяются с двух сторон запятыми) распространенные определения, выраженные причастием или прилагательным с зависящими от него словами (так называемые определительные обороты), стоящие **после** существительного или субстантивированного слова: *По пыльной дороге, **ведущей к садам,** тянулись скрипучие арбы, **наполненные чёрным виноградом*** (Л. Т.); *Нас окружал со всех сторон сплошной вековой бор, **равный по величине доброму княжеству*** (Купр.); *Стоят и те трое, **хмурые все*** (М. Г.).

• *...являясь котом,* (каким?) ***полным*** (чего?) ***фантазии и воображения...***

•• Примеры
*С другой стороны, он был **человеком, полным фантазии и отваги*** (А. Пивковская. Ахматова, то есть Россия).
*Она была ребенком, **полным фантазии и лукавого шарма*** (М. Волошин. Зеленая змея).

••• Другие моменты
Правильно — *принадлежащ**их***; *пишутся именно так, а не эдак.*
Моё предназначение среди остальных котов, принадлежащих к нашей команде...
[Так-таки](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/238990) — это частица, *эдаки* — усеченное местоименное прилагательное.

[Согласованные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)