# Что это за слово, которое из пяти букв состоит, оканчиваясь на «м»?

Tags: орфография

Что это за слово, которое из пяти букв состоит, оканчиваясь на ***м***?

Comment: Хорошее слово, начинается на М. Приличное.  Хотя и неприличным тоже может быть)  Со словами всякие истории происходят.

Comment: *Мудак*, что ль, Шерон?

Comment: Ну что вы! Я таких слов-то не знаю)  Я же говорю, приличное, но может стать оценочным.  К форуму относится,  а не к человеку.

Comment: Какое же всё-таки?

Comment: Вы догадаетесь сами, я в вас верю)  Надо угадать всего 4 буквы из 33 букв.

Comment: Ситуация как у Чехова https://ilibrary.ru/text/988/p.1/index.html   А когда догадаетесь, то не говорите вслух. Пусть этот рассказ останется без концовки)

Comment: Интересный вопрос, вроде кажется что таких слов миллион, но если не мудрить с редкими словами типа всяких бедламов, пилумов, фатумов, то в голову из простых слов что-то ничего не идет. Хотя может это я тупой, кроссворды никогда не были моей сильной стороной.

Answer (score 0):

Этим словом может быть:

- имя собственное: Артем, Любим...
- имя существительное: взлом, вотум, гарем, разум, зажим, излом, интим, проем, прием, объем, облом, нажим, миазм, мадам, режим, содом, спазм, терем, тотем, фильм, форум, шелом, шторм...
- глагол: можем, видим, сидим, стоим, любим, мочим, точим, лечим, печем...
- наречия, местоимения, числительные и пр...: даром, зачем, затем, нечем, мигом, потом, рядом, родом из, таким / сяким / любым / своим детям, все путем, оптом, в своем, в целом, пятым, сотым, пёхом, шагом, ни духом...

Comment: Да, все таки я тупой.

Comment: Зашифровано, заколдовано, с ветром в поле как будто обвенчано, нераскрытое, неизвестное, пусть останется ТАЙНОЮ ВЕЧНОЮ)

Comment: Мне тоже не дано понять, за что отдан голос этому вопросу. За изящество и точность формулировки?  За глубину и многозначность? За то, что затрагивает интереснейшую тему?

Comment: Вопрос, думаю, возник вот из этого комментария: *И еще словечко было тогда сказано, тоже верное. Из пяти букв, на М начинается. Догадайтесь, какое.* (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478186/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%90-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Вот не дают тайну сохранить эти добровольные помощники.  Мало у них чувства поэзии)  И опять у моего словечка появляется возможность быть раскрытым, а ведь я просила Лео – не говорите вслух.  Интересно, насколько реалистичен рассказ Чехова "Лошадиная фамилия"? Есть ли там элементы художественного вымысла. В жизни так мало игры, одна проза.